# Xsane not detecting Lexmark scanner since I moved my computer and set it up again

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner, lexmark

I'm using Hirsute Hippo and Lexmark supplies a driver which supports a USB scanner using Xsane.
All was well until I moved and reset up the computer.
Now Xsane 0.999 cannot detect the scanner.
Changed my USB port.
Re-downloaded the driver and used Ubuntu software to install it
Tried to download Libsane extras but cannot locate the package.
GIMP XSane plugin was another suggested solution but cannot find it.

Comment: here's a link for libsane packages https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsane, see if any of this helps.  Otherwise I'm not sure how just moving your computer could affect this.

Comment: Investigate: `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` within 4 minutes of reconnecting the scanner. Also, find the device name: `ls -lrt /dev | tail`. Does the device have group `rw`? E.g. `-rw-rw----`?

Comment: Here is the output of  journalctl:

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to be missing libsum  and libsum-dev which I added with Synaptic.
Xsane still starts but never gets beyond "Searching for devices" and then I get an error message saying Xsane is not responding.